# Two syntax errors: Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++

So I have a few syntax errors that are saying:

```
Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '* '  
Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  
Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  
Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
```

All of these are in:

```
#pragma once  
#include "World.h"  
class Organism  
{  
protected:  
    int strength;
    int initiative;    
    int age, x, y;  
    char sign;  
    World *world;  //line that makes errors
public:  
    Organism(World*,int,int);
    virtual ~Organism();
    virtual void action() = 0;
    virtual void collision() = 0;
    virtual char getSign() = 0;
};
```

I have also these errors(yeah, twice same error):

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'World'
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'World'
```

In line with Organism(World*,int,int); (I do not know how to add line numbers on StackOverflow). What can cause these problems?

Here is the World.h code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Organism.h"
class World
{
    int height;
    int width;
    Organism*** organisms;
public:
    World();
    World(int, int);
    ~World();
    void DrawWorld();
    void NextRound();
};
```

Comment: Congratulations, you are a three-star programmer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the `"Organism.h"` header file depends on the `"World.h"` header file which depends on the `"Organism.h"` and so on in infinity. It's a so-called *circular dependency*.

In your case it's very easy to break, since neither header file, as you show them, actually need the *definitions* of the other classes, only the *declarations*.

That means the `World.h` header file can look like this instead:

```
#pragma once
// Note: No #include directive here
class Organism;  // Forward-declaration of the class
class World
{
    int height;
    int width;
    Organism*** organisms;
public:
    World();
    World(int, int);
    ~World();
    void DrawWorld();
    void NextRound();
};
```

The same can be done with the `Organism.h` header file.

The source file that *uses* the classes needs the full definitions of the classes, so they need to include both header files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is circular dependencies.   That is reflected in your header files each including each other, so the definition of `World` depends on the definition of `Organism` which depends on the definition of `World`, ad infinitum.

The (non-standard) `#pragma once` might stop the header files from infinitely including each other, but does not change the fact that the types defined within them have that recursive dependence.

You need to break the dependency.   A common technique is to use forward declarations, and avoid having (at least) one of the headers relying on the other, and use declarations to break dependencies between the classes.

```
#ifndef ORGANISM_H_INCLUDED     // include guard instead of #pragma once
#define ORGANISM_H_INCLUDED

class World;   // declaration of World

class Organism  
{  
     // as you have it
};
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef WORLD_H_INCLUDED
#define WORLD_H_INCLUDED

class Organism;
class World
{
     // as you have it
};
#endif
```

The important thing to realise is that, given a class declaration (not a definition) it is only possible to work with pointers or references.

To implement member functions of both classes that rely on knowledge of both full class definitions you will need to `#include` both headers.   Based on that, your code will be able to do things like create instances of either type.